# Check if item present in ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Working on a WP7 app, need to check if a certain item is present in a combo box and also get its index. Used Contains(), IndexOf() but none returning correct result, always not found.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how did you add the items to the combo box at the first place. like add it by name, bind a data source or add it as object...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to override objects `Equals` for Contains & IndexOf of ComboBox to work, although for certain answer question doesn't contain enough detail

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT binding to a data source, then you can just use `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` to get the index.

If you are binding to a data source, e.g. a **DataSet** with a **DataTable** named **dt1**, then you can use `dt1.Rows.Count - 1` to get the index corresponding to the order of **ComboBoxItem**. You cannot get the selected index of a **ComboBoxItem** directly if you have it binded to a data source.

If the order of your data source (e.g. **DataTable**) is not in the same ordering as the **ComboBoxItem**, then you should convert your **DataTable** to a **DataView** with sorting, and bind your **ComboBox** to your **DataView**. `(DataView.ToTable as DataTable).Rows.Count - 1` will get the correct ordering, hence, Index, of the **ComboBoxItem**.